# React bootstrap rounded corners for Navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap, rounded-corners

I've recently started teaching myself a bit about React-Bootstrap and I'm trying to get the hang of customising certain elements.

I've built this Navbar below in standard JavaScript, HTML and CSS, and I'll like to replicate the rounded corners in bootstrap, and to have the links centered on each strip of the Navbar, but I'm really struggling to make this happen, and figuring out which element I should target, can anyone help please?

[image: Built using standard JavaScript, HTML and CSS]

This is what I have so far for my React-bootstrap version:

[image: React-bootstrap version]

Code for React-bootstrap that I have so far:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  NavDropdown,
  Image,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "@reach/router";
import styles from "../CSS/NavbarLinks.module.css";

function NavbarLinks(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#98c01f" }}>
      <Container>
        <Row className="nopadding">
          <Col className="no-gutters" xs={12} md={5}>
            <Navbar
              bg="light"
              variant="light"
              expand="lg"
              style={{ padding: "0px" }}
              className={styles.displayPadding}
            >
              <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
              <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/about">
                    About
                  </Nav.Link>
                  <NavDropdown title="Guinea Pigs" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                    <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/boars">
                      Boars
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/sows">
                      Sows
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/GPCareTips">
                      Care Tips
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                  </NavDropdown>
                  <NavDropdown title="Rabbits" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                    <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/bucks">
                      Bucks
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/does">
                      Does
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#rabbitCareTips">
                      Care Tips
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                  </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
          </Col>
          <Col className="no-gutters" xs={12} md={2}>
            <Link to="/">
              <center>
                <Image
                  src="/TamesideTextandLogo.png"
                  roundedCircle
                  className={styles.logo}
                />
              </center>
            </Link>
          </Col>
          <Col className="no-gutters" xs={12} md={5}>
            <Navbar
              bg="light"
              variant="light"
              expand="lg"
              style={{ padding: "0px" }}
              className={styles.displayPadding}
            >
              <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
              <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                  <NavDropdown title="Services" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                    <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/grooming">
                      Grooming
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/boarding">
                      Boarding
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                  </NavDropdown>
                  <NavDropdown title="Help Us" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                    <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/adoption">
                      Adoption
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/donations">
                      Donations
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/sponsor">
                      Sponsor
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                  </NavDropdown>
                  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/contactUs">
                    Contact
                  </Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavbarLinks;
```

and the styling CSS module:

```css
.logo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 300px;
}

.displayPadding {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .displayPadding {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

How do I made the links centered on the react-bootstrap navbar, and how to I round the corners of the navbar like my first version, can anyone help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apply css class to your menu  first menu add class  **uvs-left**  second menu class **uvs-right** and below css check below example

```
.uvs-left {border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px; padding-left: 40px;} .uvs-right {border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0; padding-right: 40px;}
```

```css
 .uvs-left {border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
    padding-left: 40px;}
    
    
   .uvs-right {border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
    padding-right: 40px;}
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
    
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark uvs-left">
  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Navbar text-->
  <span class="navbar-text">
    Navbar text
  </span>
</nav><br/><br/><br/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark uvs-right">
  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Navbar text-->
  <span class="navbar-text">
    Navbar text
  </span>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Umesh. So whereabouts would I add the classes to in my react-bootstrap code above, would it be in the <Navbar>  wrapper for each of the two separate navbars as well as the CSS styling in my other folder, or the do I put the class in each of the <Nav> components (that already has the className of "mr-auto" in my code) within each Navbar?  Sorry I'm new to this, so i'm just trying to get my head around which bit needs the class adding to it. Thanks for responding. :)

Comment: For 1st navbar  add className="uvs-left"    <Navbar bg="light" variant="light" expand="lg" style={{ padding: "0px" }} className="uvs-left">  For 2nd navbar  add className="uvs-right"  <Navbar bg="light" variant="light" expand="lg" style={{ padding: "0px" }} className="uvs-right">

Comment: After added these uvs left right classes to your navbar you can add this css in your main css file OR component css file .uvs-left {border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px; padding-left: 40px;} .uvs-right {border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0; padding-right: 40px;}

Comment: Thanks very much I've got the edges rounded now. Do you know how to centralise the links by any chance as well? :)

Comment: Add class to nav as class="text-center" OR apply css to nav margin:0 auto;  with width:80%